# Analog of MySQL \c in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I googled around and couldn't find an answer to this seemingly primitive question. When I am writing a query and want to abort some dumb stuff that I wrote in mysql I can simply use \c to start reconstructing a query.

What do I use in sqlite? Note: I am doing this from adb shell, so it does not support such a nice thing as readline lib.

Answer (score 0):

For single-line queries, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to kill the line and start over.

For multi-line queries the above only works for the line you're currently working on. For such cases, I sometimes just enter in some syntactically incorrect random keystrokes, followed by `;`, to make the parser process the query but not execute it because of the syntax error.

I prefer editing those complex queries in a real text editor and then copy-paste them to the sqlite3 prompt.

Comment: Sometimes you have to end strings with `'` or trigger bodies with `END;`.